# What is the most efficient way to distinguish and count events in a sequence of 0s and 1s?

Tags: r, dplyr, sequence

I have a sequence of 0s and 1s,

```
test = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0)
```

An event is defined by the first 0 in a subsequence of 0s. I am interested in the number of zeros (count) in each event.

For *test* above, we would have:

- Event 1: 0 0 0
- Event 2: 0
- Event 3: 0 0

So, I would like to create the following table,

| Event | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

I have started creating a function with *if* clauses. But it became too heavy to run with the long vector that I am using.

Then I started a new code with *dplyr*, but I can't get it to work it properly.

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Here's my sample (and incorrect) code:

```
library(dplyr)
test = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0)
df = data.frame(test)
df$cumsum = cumsum(df$test==0L)

df%>%
  group_by(test, cumsum)%>%
  mutate(counter=row_number())%>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: You can try `with(rle(test), data.frame(id = sequence(sum(values == 0)), count = lengths[values == 0]))`.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.